# String to List with index in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I want to convert a string like this:

```
[{firstname=yoan,lastname=spark,age=30}]
```

To an ArrayList with firstname, lastname and age as indexes

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've told us what you want to do, but given no indication of how far you've got. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service - you should show us your progress so far, and also consider things like what happens if the first name has a comma in it. It's also not clear what you mean by "as indexes" here - do you mean properties?

Comment: i want to convert this String to An XML format So i should use an ArrayList to do this => result:  `<firstname>yoan<firstname><lastname>spark<lastname><age>yoan<age>`
firstname, lastname and age must be indexes of the ArrayList

Comment: I don't think your question is so bad.  It appears you are a new user and still learning java.  Before posting you should try  researching your question a little bit. I went into google and did a search on "Java use string as index"  try  that and see what you get.  Seems like it would be a  little work to get what you want which leads me to believe there might be a better way to do what you actually want to get done.  There's no way of telling from your question. You'll find the more work you put into your questions the better answers you'll get from the community.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve your required results is that you can use a **Map** of java. Let say if you use **HashMap** with key and value as string. Then with the key as firstname, lastname and age will working as indexes for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Map for this.You will accomplished the desired result.

```
HashMap hashMap= new HashMap();
hashMap.put("firstname", "yoan");
hashMap.put("lastname", "spark");
hashMap.put("age", "63");
//to get object from map you can iterate 
    Iterator keyIterator = hashMap.keySet().iterator();
            while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String)keyIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Field=" + key + "  value=" + hashMap.get(key));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a Person object with the data you want to look for.

```
public class Person {
public String firstname;
public String lastname;
public String age;
    public Person(String firstnameinput, String lastnameinput, String ageinput) {
        firstname = firstnameinput;
        lastname = lastnameinput;
        age = ageinput;
    }
}
```

Then make a function that will get a Person by firstname, lastname, or age.

```
public Person getPerson(String find, Person[] l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        Person p = l[i];
        String a = p.age;
        String fn = p.firstname;
        String ln = p.lastname;
        if (find.equals(a) || find.equals(fn) || find.equals(ln)) {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return null; //if the person does not exist in the list
}
```